# Loop Rule Parts Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

[image: Loop Rule]
[Loop Rule Diagram]

The problem is thus: Apply the loop rule to abcdefghia and find the expression which adds to zero. 
I tried this, but I was not able to get it correct. I know that when crossing a resistor in the same direction as the current, the voltage is negative, but against the current it is positive. When going with the current from a positive to negative terminal, the voltage is negative, whereas from negative to a positive terminal is positive. The opposite applies if going against the current. I do not need a numerical answer, because the loop adds up to zero, but I would want to understand how to properly add up the voltages. I tried this on the first attempt: -"$I_1$$R_1$+$E_1$-$r_1$$I_1$-$R_5$$I_1$-$r_4$$I_1$-$E_4$+$r_3$$I_3$+$E_3$, but I got sign errors. I tried four other sign permutations but  I also got errors. I also don't know in what direction the current goes for the b-d or h-j branches, because $I_2$ is not in the given symbols used to input an answer. If someone could walk me  through a step-by-step symbolic solution, I would be grateful, because I tried 5 times and could not get the correct answer (the system only allows 10 attempts to any problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the required equation

$$I_1R_1-E_1+I_1r_1+I_1r_5+I_3r_4+E_4+I_3r_3-E_3+I_3R_3=0$$

If you encounter a negative terminal first when moving along the loop then the voltage is negative and if you encounter the positive terminal first the voltage is taken as positive.Hope this helped.

Comment: What are you trying to say? The equation is illegible.

Comment: How is it illegible?